# Bootstrap 4 - Dropdown value population

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a dropdown button in Bootstrap 4, like
[this](http://jsfiddle.net/u8L5mefx/13/).

```html
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
   Source
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Source 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Source 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Source 3</a>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I wanted the text of the dropdown to change to the value I selected.

Can this be possible in Bootstrap 4?

Comment: Using plant Bootstrap it is not possible. Use the JS/JQuery or some framework like Angular to store the dropdown text in the variable and then switch it to property you clicking on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using plain bootstrap this is not possible. In your jsfiddle it seems you have jquery available so you can add a small snippet like

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu a").click(function(){

        $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
        $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u8L5mefx/17/